# What's the next step if I request an account deletion and after a reasonable amount of time, nothing happens?

Tags: support, deleted-accounts

I recently requested deletion of my Stack Exchange account on just one specific Stack Exchange site.  I followed the instructions here: [How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account)

I made the request nine calendar days ago.  Then I waited.  Then I waited some more.  Then after a week, I used the contact form to try to request an update.

There's been no update, no communication, nothing except the "scheduled for deletion" banner on my account on that site.

I get that people are busy and such.  All I'm looking for is some quick indicator that something is happening, or at least is genuinely going to happen in the future.

What's the procedure for getting such an update if it's not coming from the individual site itself?

Comment: Nothing much more for us to say here other than what's in the FAQ, [How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account). Just contact them and wait.

Comment: Also see [What can highly-active users who want to delete their accounts expect if their account is held up for review for vote preservation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326965/what-can-highly-active-users-who-want-to-delete-their-accounts-expect-if-their-a)

Comment: "Varies. Generally someone only checks that queue once a week, on either a Monday or a Friday. But sometimes they forget."  That's interesting information.

Comment: See also: [Provide explanation to high reputation users that deleting their accounts may take longer than 24 hours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302013/provide-explanation-to-high-reputation-users-that-deleting-their-accounts-may-ta) - higher rep takes longer due to review process.

Comment: Update: That account deletion has gone through.

Answer (score 3):

Practically - drop the cm team a line through the contact us link. Assuming you have too much activity on the site for automatic account deletion, someone will need to look through your account, dissociate votes and so on And sometimes things slip through the cracks.

Comment: Could you link to the exact "contact us" link or form I'd need to use to do this?

Comment: Eep. It got renamed to contact at some point. It's at the bottom of the page. I suspect since 'i want to delete my user profile' is there, you might know where it is. Other seems like a logical option, then explain the situation

Comment: Right, but should I use the contact form on the site I want to delete from, or on the meta for that site, or the one here on meta.SE, or do they all go to the same place...?

Comment: Good question. I don't work here but I'm under the impression they get fed into the support/ticketing system. Using the specific site seems like a better idea.

Comment: Which site you contact from generally doesn't matter. The devs process all of them through a single queue on Stack Overflow anyways. We'd have to be having a *really* bad day to manage killing the wrong profile. Sometimes I'd rather our contact form always redirect to a single form on one domain just to remove the confusion surrounding the fact that which site you contact from doesn't matter.